# unusual behaviour of cout

Tags: c++, cout

The program runs fine and produces the intended output when run using Codeblocks IDE (uses g++ compiler). But when run on the linux terminal using the g++ compiler, the cout statements are behaving unusually and is not printing half of the statements. I have pasted just the print function of the entire code.

```
void print_result(int dist[], int previous[], int source, int destination)
{
    int temp = destination, n=1;
     answer[0] = destination;
    cout<<"\n The shortest distance from the "<<names[source]<<" to "<<names[destination]<<" is: "<<dist[destination]<<endl;
    cout<<"The path from the "<<names[source]<<" to "<<names[destination]<<" is:"<<endl;
    while(temp != source)    // the previous of the node is recorded until the source is reached
    {
        answer[n] = previous[temp];//the previous of all the nodes from the destination to the source is recorded
        temp = previous[temp];
        n = n+1;
    }
     for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--) // since the previous loop was run n-1 times, it is clear that there are n-1 vertices between the source and the destination
     {
         cout<<" "<<nodes[answer[i]]<<" ("<<names[answer[i]]<<")";//the path is printed from source to destination
         if(i!=0)          // this condition is just to make sure that the arrow is not printed for the last element
         {
             cout<<"  -->";
         }
     }
}
```

The output that I get in the codeblocks IDE is,

```
Enter the source node 44
Enter the destination node 82
The shortest distance from the  Mathews Arena to  East village is: 811
The path from the  Mathews Arena to  East village is:
44 ( Mathews Arena)  --> 45 ( Gainsborough Parking Garage)  --> 47 ( Cullinane hall)  --> 82 ( East village)
```

But the output that I get in the linux terminal is,

```
Enter the source node 44
 Enter the destination node 82
 is: 811t villagetance from the  Mathews Arena
 is: East village  Mathews Arena
```

Not able to understand why my cout statements doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: There are `\r` characters in your file. Check for dos line endings.

Comment: The problem is not in the source code you have provided. The problem is in the program as a whole and how that program operates. You have provided insufficient information to provide anything other than an educated guess as to what the problem is. However there is a suggestion that the data in the `names` array, which are strings, have a carriage return in them so when the name is written out, the carriage return causes the Linux terminal to move the cursor back to the beginning of the line of output and overwrite what has already been written. The Codeblocks IDE may not be doing that behavior

Comment: I also feel that you are using a Windows generated text file, and using it in a Linux environment.  Note where the bad behavior starts -- right after the end of each of those output statements, indicating you're reading those city names from a text file incorrectly.  Convert the text file to Unix / Linux text format first, then rerun your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was that I used a windows generated file in the linux environment. Thanks for helping me out.